# ComboBox IsEditable Behavior question WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding}">
  <ComboBoxItem>Angus/ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>Angie/ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>Jane</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>Steve</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

I would like to allow the user to find their selection by typing in a name, so I have set IsEditable equal to true.

Now my question regarding behavior is this:
When I start typing Ang...I would expect to see BOTH Angus and Angie in the dropdown....however, I only see Angie first and I dont see Angus until I enter Angu ... .
Can we replicate this behavior like in google search autocomplete box.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you can't do it with the regular ComboBox, but the good news are:

There's an excellent autoCompleteBox in the WPF toolkit.
this is an example how to use it:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/537/